# How to output array of embedded documents?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a `Movies` collection with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5f4fbb10c90790a35f78474b"},
    "title":"Mother to Earth",
    "year":2020,
    "description":"A group of simps tries to find the source of an obscure meme game.",
    "screenings":
        [
            {
                "screeningID":{"$oid":"5f4fbb10c90790a35f78474a"},
                "timedate":"2020-09-29, 18:00PM",
                "tickets":50
            }
        ]
}
```

I want to make a query that outputs the array matching `screeningID`. In this case, the output should be:

```
{
    "screeningID":{"$oid":"5f4fbb10c90790a35f78474a"},
    "timedate":"2020-09-29, 18:00PM",
    "tickets":50
}
```

However, when I do a `find` query, it outputs the entry for the whole movie. How do I make it output exactly the array I want in `screenings`?

Comment: Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/k7bC8KZL6yd help you?

Comment: Do you store the timedate as string? You should not do that, store proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use projections , i.e pass second parameter {screenings:1}
Here 1 means true!!

Comment: I'm using the command `screening = movies.find_one({'screenings.screeningID': ObjectId(data['screening'])}, {'screenings':1, '_id':0})`, where `data['screening']` is the target `screeningID`. As is right now, it shows all objects in the `screenings` array. How do I make it output just the one that matches the `screeningID`?

Comment: Have you tried screenings.0 :1, since it is array!!